# Missing mounting brackets for doorway pull bar. Alternatives?

Tags: pull-ups, exercise-equipment

I recently got a pull up bar from a friend, but he was missing the mounting brackets/cups to put it up in the doorway. Since I can't find the mounting brackets sold separately anywhere on the internet, I'm thinking of heading to the hardware store to find an alternative.

The pull up bar is similar to this: https://www.amazon.ca/Everlast-EX2405BK-Chinning-Sit-Black/dp/B00091RXLY/ref=sr_1_1?s=sports&ie=UTF8&qid=1466453777&sr=1-1&keywords=pull+up+bar

Plumbing flanges are unlikely to work because the molding on our doorways protrudes (inwards) and is exactly the same size as the diameter of the bar, so there is no space for the outer ring (though, I could only screw it in in 2 places — the top and the bottom)

I am considering trying a PVC cap, with holes drilled into the bottom, though I have concerns about it's ability to hold up my weight.

Any other ideas or suggestions? Do you know where I can get pull up bar mounting brackets? Do you think a PVC cap will hold?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about parts for a piece of equipment, not how to use the equipment in a program.

Answer (score 1):

The PVC cap may of may not work depending on your weight.

This design looks attractive to me if you are able to adopt it to fit your specifications:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Doorframe-Chin-up-Bar/